# why I am getting waiting for task kill to chrome while executing automation script

Tags: appium, ui-automation, remotewebdriver

Sometimes I got stuck to wait for approx 5 min when executed the script on appium using remote web drive. Any Suggestion to remove this or reduce the time will be appreciated.` Following is the logon appium

> info: Chromedriver: Killing any old chromedrivers, running: FOR /F
>   "usebackq tokens=5" %a in (`netstat -nao ^| findstr /R /C:"9502 "`) do
>   (FOR /F "usebackq" %b in (`TASKLIST /FI "PID eq %a" ^| findstr /I
>   chromedriver.exe`) do (IF NOT %b=="" TASKKILL /F /PID %a))

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill chromedrivers manually before you start appium connection. In windows I use below code,

```
if (IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/C", "taskkill /f /im chromedriver.exe"});
        }
```